# Delete ugly ?pg=1 from URL via .htacess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have pagination plugin in my CMS which produces ?pg=1 links. I want to redirect this url without this ugly postfix because without it CMS shows first page too.

So, i have url like `http://site.ru/category/schock-crane/?pg=1` or `http://site.ru/moyka/?type=granit&pg=1`
I want to redirect such urls to `http://site.ru/category/schock-crane/` and `http://site.ru/moyka/?type=granit` respectly.

I tried this .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule (.*)(&|\?)pg=1$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried this regexp code at regexp trainers - it worked. But at live server no redirect happens.

Here is whole .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # fix /?pg=1
    RewriteRule (.*)(&|\?)pg=1$ $1 [R=301,L]

    # fix .palitra-tab
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -tab$
    RewriteRule (.*)/([0-9]*)/\.(.*)-tab?$ http://site.ru/redirect.php?id=$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/csss/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule csss/(.*)\.css$ css.php?n=$1 [L]

    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/csss/(.*) /test.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/base([0-9]+)/?$ $1?base=$2 

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    #RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ /images/watermark/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on the remote server? What happens if you remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` condition?

Comment: mod_rewrite works - CMS successfully uses clean-url

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RewriteCond` to examine the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)pg=1(&(.*)|$)
RewriteCond %1%4 (.*?)&?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L]
```

The second `RewriteCond` is just to remove a trailing `&`.

Comment: Didn't work - no url redirect happens. Tried without secnd line of your example - no success too. Can you test this at your server?

Comment: @the_ghost: I’ve tested it and it works for the test cases `?pg=1`, `?&pg=1`, `?pg=1&`, `?foo&pg=1`, and `?pg=1&foo`. Just make sure that you put this rule in front of those rules that just do an internal rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the missing `^` or `/` kills the redirect

```
# fix /?pg=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)(&|\?)pg=1$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

or try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(&|\?)pg=1$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```